# Appending created jquery dom elements

Tags: jquery

```
var $td = $('<td/>');
var $tr = $('<tr/>');

$td.text('something');

<table></table>
```

What i want to do is something like:

```
$('table').append($tr + $td);
```

What would be the correct syntax here? Thanks

Comment: `$('table').append('<tr><td>something</td></tr>');` will work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('table').append($tr).find('tr:last').append($td);
```

That should firstly append the `tr` element to the table, you then need to find the the `tr` element within the table and append the `td` to that. Thanks to Jasper for pointing out that the `find('tr')`  was required.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hbzJf/1

Comment: That makes this HTML which is not valid: `<table><tbody><tr></tr></tbody><td>something</td></table>`. It appends a `<tr>` to the `<table>` element and then appends a `<td>` to the `<table>` element. You could change it like so: `$('table').append($tr).find('tr').append($td);`

Comment: One thing I noticed about your update is that it will append `$td` to all `<tr>` elements in the table, not only the one just appended. I guess the most simple fix would be: `$('table').append($tr).find('tr:last').append($td);`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it all at once:

```
$('table').append('<tr><td>something</td></tr>');
```

Or

```
$('<tr><td>something</td></tr>').appendTo('table');
```

Comment: +1, all at once is better for performance as well, the less DOM manipulation, the better.

Comment: @Jasper It will get messy since i want to add an input field with a lot of data-properties. I guess i can keep the table cells on a string-level and use find + append for the  input field i suppose?

Comment: @Johan It's a good idea to concoct a string (or array that you `.join('')` into a string) and then append that single string to the DOM. `$('table').append('<tr data-foo="bar"><td data-bar="foo">something in <span data-nothing="something">here</span></td></tr>');` is how I would do it. If you need to iterate through a loop to build your output then just add the output to a string variable on each loop.

Comment: @Jasper I would prefer using properties on the dom element. But ill guess i have to do it this way.. Since the .data method doesnt add the data-whatever attribute to the html anyway if i recall correctly. Thanks